Как разбить число на разряды в python?
Любое Число должно вводиться через import sys.
Например если ввести 12345678 должны получить ответ 12 345 678.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Ну блин, если просто вбить заголовок вопроса в гyгл, то первая же ссылка ведёт прямо на этот сайт

Дубликат: Как разбить число на разряды

x = 12345678
s = '{0:,}'.format(x)
print(s.replace(',', '_'))


Подчёркивания гораздо проще получить: print(f'{n:_d}'). Но автору нужны не подчёркивания, а пробелы. )

для того что бы у меня приняли это задание, нужно что бы число 12345678 или любое другое вводилось через параметр которое мы вводим перед запуском программы, (Пример запуска программы с параметром в виде числа 12345678 : > python th.py 12345678)
Я никак не могу подружить все найденные решения в интернете, с моей задачей так как везде числа уже даны как переменная X = 12345678, от меня требуют через
import sys
number = sys.argv[1]
За ранее спасибо

import sys;x = int(sys.argv[1]); остальной код
